# Limit of monotonic increasing functions is again montonic increasing

Tags: real-analysis, monotone-functions, pointwise-convergence

Let $f_n:\mathbb{R}\to [0,1]$ be monotonically increasing, that is $f_{n}(x)\leq f_n(y)$ for all $x\leq y$. If $f_n\to f$ pointwise a.e., does it follow that $f$ is also monotonically increasing, so is $f(x)\leq f(y)$ for all $x\leq y$ ?

Comment: The limit would be $f(x)=0$ on $[0,1)$ and $f(1)=1$ and hence for all $x\leq y$ it holds $f(x)\leq f(y)$ or am I wrong ?

Comment: @MichaelMorrow $f_n(x)$ converges to $x\mapsto 0$ of $x\neq 1$ and $x\mapsto 1$ if $x=1$. this is still monotonic increasing by the OP’s definition

Comment: Yeah I just realized that. I believe this to actually be true.

Comment: Maybe like this: Let $N$ be the nullset so that $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus N$. Then we have $f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)\leq \lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(y)=f(y).$ Or maybe easier ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does a.e. (however, it is not necessarily true that it holds everywhere)

To see this, fix $x<y$ in the set where $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$. Now suppose that $f(x)>f(y)$. In particular, let's write $f(x) = f(y) + 2\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0$. Now, we know from the definition of pointwise convergence that there exists an $N$ such that for all $n>N$ $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$, and there also exists an $M$ such that for all $m>M$ we have that $|f_m(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$.

Now pick a $j>\max{N,M}$ Then $f_j(y) < f_j(x) + \epsilon$, and $f_j(x) > f_j(x) + \epsilon$.

This contradicts the monotonicism of $f_j(x)$

However, we cannot get a strong result to hold everywhere. To see this, we can just change a single point, e.g. if $f_n(x) = x-\frac{1}{n}$, and $f(x) = x$ for $x$ not equal to $1$, and $f(1)=0$. Then $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$, and $f_n$ is monotonic, but $f$ is not monotonic.

Comment: I see..., is my "proof" above valid, i.e. just going back to a set where we convergence everywhere and then use the convergence

Comment: Depends how rigorous you want to be. In general in an introductory analysis course you would prove from scratch things like 'if $x_n =< y_n$ for all n, and $x_n$ tends to x, and $y_n$ tends to y, then $x<=y$, whereas once you are more confident, you can state results like this without proof. I in essence gave a direct proof of this, with $f_n(x)$ and $f_n(y)$ being the two sequences

Comment: So your proof is fine, if you are comfortable to assume that result. As a rule of thumb, if you are unsure if you know how to prove it, I would prove it.